# Como forçar uma Exception ao tentar excluir um registro Master que já contenha relacionamento em um Registro Child?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, relacionamento

Criei a seguinte estrutura no SQL Server:

[image: relação]

Usando o EntityFramework com Code-First as classes ficaram dessa forma:

```cs
[Table("Master")]
public class Master
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Table("Child")]
public class Child
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Master")]
    public int? MasterId { get; set; }
    public virtual Master Master { get; set; }
}
```

Veja que **`MasterId`** por ser nulo (**`int?`**).

Ainda assim, setando a ***Foreign key*** criada em **`Child`** para não deletar em cascata (setando ***No Action***) esperava que ao tentar excluir um registro em **`Master`**, que já tenha sido relacionado na **`Child`**, gerasse uma ***Exception***.

Atentando para o fato de eu ter removido as convenções de deleção em cascata:

```cs
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext()
        : base("Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=TestFK; Integrated Security=True")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Master> Masters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Delete with No Acton]

Então testei isso esperando receber uma ***Exception***, mas não ocorreu:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new DataContext())
        {
            ctx.Masters.Add(new Master { Id = 22 });
            ctx.Childs.Add(new Child { Description = "Teste 1", MasterId = 22 });
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            var versao = ctx.Masters.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 22);
            if (versao != null)
            {
                ctx.Masters.Remove(versao); // <-- esperava que isso geraria uma exception
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do contrário, o registro foi excluído e o valor em ***Child*** foi setado como ***null***.

[image: select em master após o processo]

[image: select em child após o processo]

Como forçar essa ***Exception***?
Faltou alguma configuração? É um comportamento padrão?

---

Para concluir, a operação sendo feita diretamente no banco de dados retorna uma **`Exception`**, como esperado.

[image: Operação feita manualmente]

Comment: Porque é que quer que o MasterId possa ser null?

Comment: Olá @ramaral! Bom, claro que esse é apenas um pequeno exemplo em relação ao meu real problema. E **`MasterId`** em **`Child`** pode ficar um bom tempo ou até nunca receber uma referência de **`Master`**,

Comment: Aí está a resposta à sua pergunta. O EntityFramework comporta-se assim porque, quando indica que MasterId pode ser nulo, você está indicando que quer filhos sem pais. O EntityFramework não tem como adivinhar que você só quer isso em algumas situações.

Comment: @ramaral, entendi. Mas isso deve ter alguma forma de se contornar, já que não é o comportamento padrão do SQL Server. Conforme acabei de atualizar a pergunta mostrando que manualmente é gerado uma exceção.

Comment: Estranho! Não vejo porque o comportamento seja diferente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## É um comportamento padrão?

É. Repare que seu `Master` (o registro pai) pode ser nulo no filho (é chamado de "registro órfão"), portanto não haveria motivo para gerar exceção já que seu banco permite esta exclusão. O que o Entity Framework faz é arrumar os registros pra você de forma a assegurar consistência relacional.

Neste caso, levantar exceção seria uma regra de negócio:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new DataContext())
        {
            ctx.Masters.Add(new Master { Id = 22 });
            ctx.Childs.Add(new Child { Description = "Teste 1", MasterId = 22 });
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            var versao = ctx.Masters.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 22);

            if (ctx.Childs.Any(c => c.MasterId == versao.Id)) {
                throw new Exception("Não é possível excluir registro pai que tenha filhos.");
            }

            // Comentei porque SingleOrDefault dá exceção quando o registro vem nulo, 
            // então esse condicional não faz muito sentido.
            // if (versao != null)
            // {
                ctx.Masters.Remove(versao); // <-- esperava que isso geraria uma exception
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            // }
        }
    }
}
```

## Sobre a exceção

O Entity Framework primeiro define `MasterId` em `Child` como `null` antes de excluir `Master` porque conhece o relacionamento e sabe que tem ali uma chave estrangeira.

Comment: Pelo o que entendi, apesar do "***No Action***", o EntityFramework ignora e assume um "***Set Null***". Não existe uma forma de contornar isso no Banco? Pergunto, apesar de você já ter dito que a solução é na aplicação. Preciso assegurar isso pelo banco de dados também.

Comment: No banco dá pra fazer por *trigger*, mas fica dependente de tecnologia. O ideal é resolver via regra de negócio. Tem gente que não vai gostar do que eu vou dizer, mas a regra poderia ser resolvida num *Controller* ou num *Helper*.

Comment: Ok! Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Cigano, viu a alteração à pergunta? Consegue dar uma explicação para isso?

Comment: @ramaral, setar null é do próprio EntityFramework.

Comment: @ramaral Atualizei a resposta.